# Asp.net user is logged out when browser closes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session

I'm currently working on an ASP.net application. There is one situation that's happening and I don't understand why:

I use asp.net Identity for login. If I login into the application and then completely close the browser and open the application again, I get logged out. If I log into the application -> open another tab -> close the previous tab -> open the application in the new tab, I stay logged in.

So what exactly is happening when I close the browser and get logged out? And where can I find the method in code that causes this? Note that this was the default application behavior and nothing was changed regarding sessions in code.

Comment: **Can you provide the code snippet?**

Comment: This is default behavior of the app so I don't know what in the code is triggering this behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what browser are you using? There is session life time configuration in .net, but look like it's your cookies got clear or invalid whenever you closed. The tab window is nothing special but share the same storage/cookies and any browser resources. You still be able to login because your cookies still exist/valid, only kill the tab will not log you out because your browser cookies remain holding the valid token to the server.